# how to perform mutliple select statements in node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

how to perform multiple select statements in node.js ? or is there any better way than multiple select statement for the below requirement.

```
table_tournament_master:
          `tournament_id`
           tournament_id_01
           tournament_id_02 ,

table_tournament_id_01_registered:
          `payer_user_id`
table_tournament_id_02_registered:
          `payer_user_id`
....
```

So as ilustrated above , whenever there is new tournament I am creating a table associated with it dynamically . Here the user can register for others also which means his entries are multiple in each tournament table , Now , I want to know how many times he has registered to the tournament .

I want each tournament table registrations in form of array which has the count of his registrations in that tournament .

and the question for multiple select statements is that , I am using react js where I render a cards view for all the tournaments and I want to display no of registrations he has done already with respect to that tournamemt. and I want to send one request to my backend node.js to fetch all user registrations till date for each tournament , preferrably an array so that it would be easy to use

Comment: Can you show the `select` statements that you're talking about?

Comment: No , I am asking how to perform such select statement

`select count(*) from 20200611t7_players where payer_info='ritteshstark@gmail.com';
select count(*) from 20200612t5_players where payer_info='ritteshstark@gmail.com';`

Comment: How to perform *what* select statement? `select` is used for executing different actions based on the value of an expression. What expression and values are you talking about?

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of `switch`, not `select`.

Comment: `SELECT payer_info, COUNT(*) from ... GROUP BY payer_info`

Comment: can you please read the scenario and answer , i have metioned it clearly , you select statement is not completely solving my scenario

Comment: It's bad design to have dynamic tables like that, it makes writing general queries very difficult. Dynamic information should be in table contents, not table and column names.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question and answering it .